# How implement DropShadow / Shadow effect at Images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to do something like a  two Images in a Stack (one of them filled with black color obviously) with a BackDropFilter. But the result blurs everything bellow of the Stack (even on alpha area of the image). I`d searched about this effect but dont have found the answers yet. i'll appreciate if you can give me a possible solution or path to implement this effect.

````
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRect(
                        child: BackdropFilter(                      
                        child:Image.asset('assets/leopard.png', color: Colors.black,),
                        filter: prefix0.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Image.asset('assets/leopard.png',),
                    ] ,```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLKYo.jpg
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use [simple_shadow](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_shadow). Here's the example from the project:

```
SimpleShadow(
    child: Image.asset('images/bird.png'),
    opacity: 0.6,         // Default: 0.5
    color: Colors.blue,   // Default: Black
    offset: Offset(5, 5), // Default: Offset(2, 2)
    sigma: 7,             // Default: 2
)
```

I've verified this works even with [flutter_svg](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image in a material and add an elevation, that should add the shadow effect. 
E.g.

```dart
    Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      child: Image.asset('assets/leopard.png',),)
```

Edit: Adding a box shadow to a PNG file (If i got you right on the Leopard).
Use two images, assuming that the leopard's background is transparent,

```dart
  Stack(
    children :<Widget>[
      Opacity(child: Image.asset(imagePath, color: Colors.black), opacity: 0.2),
      ClipRect(child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
        child: Image.asset(imagePath)))],)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this render a shadow in all edges of the image (Rectangle). I need this shadow outline the leopard, you know?

Comment: @MatheusBronca I think you need to add the Boxdecoration for your image asset to add shadow effect, please refer to this blog post https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-boxdecoration-cheat-sheet-72cedaa1ba20 If you need anything more, don't hesitate to reach out to me. Here is my email id hscharan2010@gmail.com

Comment: i'm just replying this comment to say that solution does'nt work, if anyone has any other solution my question still remains unanswered. Thanks for support @hemandroid

Comment: @MatheusBronca try the edited solution. I also hope i understood you well on the leopard background. I assume you wanted to add a box shadow to a PNG image.

Comment: @IkeMawira  That's work, i did this before, but when i put this stack above of any Widget, he's blurring everything bellow. Any solution?

Comment: @MatheusBronca use this filter instead, ```ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 0.0, sigmaY: 0.0)```. I guess the blur is because of this.

Comment: @IkeMawira Yes, this works for perfect stroke shadows, but i want a shadow with spread radius (blurred)). I think this is possible only by CustomPaint, but i don't know how implement.

Answer (score 0):

i used a package [drop shadow](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_shadow) it can create a shadow for any widget in flutter.

Comment: Please don't just recommend a library without any information about what the library is or how, specifically, it can be used to solve this specific problem. [Learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605).